# Firebase console.log on localhost?

Tags: firebase, logging, google-cloud-functions

Picking up a Firebase project that I left last spring I don't remember how `console.log` works under `firebase server`.

I have a function (that works) where I try to write some debugging info. Like this:

```
exports.myfun = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    console.log("---- does this show up somewhere???");
    ...
```

I run this locally (with `firebase serve`) and expected to see the output from `console.log` in the command line window where I started the server. But there is nothing.

Where does the output go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to downgrade the firebase-tools version. See the accepted answer here:

[The Cloud Functions emulator requires the module "firebase-admin" to be installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56068579/the-cloud-functions-emulator-requires-the-module-firebase-admin-to-be-installe)

---

EDIT: Though quite disturbingly Firebase still says:

```
Update available 6.8.0 → 6.9.1       │
   Run npm i -g firebase-tools to update
```

Doing that will make everything fail again...

I did tell Google some 10 hours ago. Something is not working about the feedback, I think.