# The Cloud Functions emulator requires the module "firebase-admin" to be installed

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

Continuing to try to get `firebase serve` to work again. I just asked this question (and got a good reply, thanks):
[npm ERR! peer dep missing: firebase-admin@^7.0.0, required by firebase-functions@2.3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56068283/npm-err-peer-dep-missing-firebase-admin7-0-0-required-by-firebase-functions)

When doing `npm list firebase-admin` I now see the expected output `-- firebase-admin@7.3.0`.

However `firebase serve` still does not work. I get this:

```
!  Your requested "node" version "6" doesn't match your global version "10"
...
!  The Cloud Functions emulator requires the module "firebase-admin" to be installed. This package is in your package.json, but it's not available. You probably need to run "npm install" in your functions directory.
i  functions: Your functions could not be parsed due to an issue with your node_modules (see above)
```

So `firebase serve` still does not see the `firebase-admin` module. What is going on? What should I do?

Comment: Seeing the same thing. Also tried node 8 and node 10 and didn't work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61489395/3273962

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was seeing the same thing and it looks like you can [downgrade your firebase-tools version to 6.8.0](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/1262)

`npm install firebase-tools@6.8.0 -g`

(I've tried this and it works)

Comment: Thanks, this works. And it also solved the problem I reported here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56026747/firebase-console-log-on-localhost

Comment: This did not work for me.  The emulator hits the function that is deployed to firebase instead of serving it from localhost.

Answer (score 8):

It looks like this issue now relates to the Node version you have installed locally.

I don't know the answer off the top of my head, but start looking around the node versions.

In your functions/package.json - it may be that you need to specify which node version to use (https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions):

```js
// functions/package.json

{
  "name": ...,
  "scripts": ...,
  "dependencies": ...,
  
  "engines": {
    "node": "10"
  }
 
}
```

Just be aware Node 10 is still in beta on Firebase.

Comment: setting `"node": "8"` might also be an option.

Comment: Thanks. I have installed `nvm` and is now using version 8. And I have changed to `"node": "8"`. I have deleted `package-lock.json` and `node_modules` and ran `npm install`. I still get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Basically it means that you should downgrade to either Node 6 or 8 not
upgrade to 10 (As the node version in your system is 10 while Firebase is requesting version 6).   Firebase does not yet support Node 10+ or even the latest version which is 12.15.0

Comment: now firebase-admin supports node 10 and above versions. they have mentioned that on their npm library page.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase-admin

Answer (score 0):

Delete the `node_module` folder.
Run `npm install` again, in the directory containing `package.json`.
This solved my problem.