# how to change node version? "Your requested "node" version "8" doesn't match your global version "10"

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-cli

It happen when I run in terminal firebase emulators:start

bellow all output

```
i  emulators: Starting emulators: functions, hosting
✔  hub: emulator hub started at ht tp://localhost:4400
⚠  Your requested "node" version "8" doesn't match your global version "10"
✔  functions: functions emulator started at ht tp://localhost:5001
i  hosting: Serving hosting files from: dist/spa-mat
✔  hosting: Local server: ht tp://localhost:5000
✔  hosting: hosting emulator started at http://localhost:5000
i  functions: Watching "/var/w ww/html/teachers/agnos2108-app.teachersnow-6391de281bf3/functions" for Cloud Functions...
✔  functions[sendEmailLogger]: http function initialized (ht tp://localhost:5001/teachernow-7082b/us-central1/sendEmailLogger).
✔  functions[sendMail]: http function initialized (ht tp://localhost:5001/teachernow-7082b/us-central1/sendMail).
✔  functions[payClbBNKTN2019ID]: http function initialized (ht tp://localhost:5001/teachernow-7082b/us-central1/payClbBNKTN2019ID).
✔  functions[payClbBNKTN2019]: http function initialized (ht tp://localhost:5001/teachernow-7082b/us-central1/payClbBNKTN2019).
✔  functions[payClbCCTN2019]: http function initialized (ht tp://localhost:5001/teachernow-7082b/us-central1/payClbCCTN2019).
✔  functions[payClbCDTN2019]: http function initialized (ht tp://localhost:5001/teachernow-7082b/us-central1/payClbCDTN2019).
i  functions[SchedulesOn]: function ignored because the database emulator does not exist or is not running.
i  functions[UsersOn]: function ignored because the database emulator does not exist or is not running.
i  functions[BankslipOn]: function ignored because the database emulator does not exist or is not running.
i  functions[sendWelcomeEmail]: function ignored because the auth emulator does not exist or is not running.
✔  emulators: All emulators started, it is now safe to connect.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply go to the node.js official website and download the version you want and install it.
or you can use nvm to do that.

for nvm you have to install nvm from https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm there you will have the a command to install nvm and after installation you have to restart your temrminal.

then use this command-

```
nvm install 12.16.1
```

12.16.1 is the version you can change it with the version you want.

Comment: worked, I follow the readme of the nvm, after type 

```nvm install 8```

Comment: great @PauloMatos

Comment: you can accept or upvote answer if it solves your issue

Comment: can you change your aswer for specific version?
In my case was `8`, but for other people could be other version).

Comment: you can use it for any version you want @PauloMatos

Answer (score 7):

The message is not indicating an error. It's just letting you know that your package.json declares a target node version of 8, but you are using node 10 on your machine for emulation.  It's not likely an issue.

If you want to get rid of the message, you should install node 8 instead of node 10 on your machine and use that instead.

Answer (score 2):

After you have installed `NVM` as suggested above, you should check your `package.json` in your project directory and update the `"engines":` value to your global version of node which is `10` in your case.

`example package.json`

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "8"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "firebase-admin": "^8.10.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.6.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^5.12.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.0.1",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

After you have updated the value `engines:` to `10` save and execute `firebase emulators:start`

Comment: When I changed it for any value, I have other problem in quasar, it dont got to do quasar build

Comment: The value you change in your `package.json` should correspond with the node version you have installed on your machine. Run `nvm list` to see what version you are currently on and update your `package.json` accordingly.